# How to Capture Vive's USB-Audio Data from Playback Devices

Tags: audio, htc-vive

I am developing a music visualizer software for Vive so I am trying to get FFT data from music that users listen to. However, I couldn't take any data from USB audio devices versus my soundcard.

What I have done is

1. Using **FMOD**, I could access recording devices but there is no usb-audio device in the recording device list so I can only access the speaker(What U Hear)

> system->recordStart(0, sound, true); // only I can capture data from recording devices
>   system->playSound(FMOD_CHANNEL_FREE,
>   sound, false, &channel);

2. Using **WASAPI** in Windows SDK, I tried to get the data although It also takes only data from the speaker not USB-Audio. 
   I am not sure I did correct here but the SDK's example, WASAPICaptureSharedTimerDriven, doesn't seem to work for USB-AUDIO but it works fine with data from my soundcard (What U Hear)

If anyone has captured any audio data through USB-audio, please tell me the approach.

Comment: Does it transfer audio over USB? Not HDMI?

Comment: @Byte56 Yes over USB not HDMI

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit outside my expertise, but you might need to use the [USBAudio class system driver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/audio/rendering-and-capturing-audio-content-by-using-the-usbaudio-driver).